# Accessing iCloud Drive Desktop From Terminal

Tags: terminal, icloud

I need to access (in order to set up fast lane) a file on my iCloud Desktop. I would prefer for this file to remain here but have had difficulty accessing it.

I have already tried the following commands:

```
cd ~/Library/Mobile\ Desktop/com~apple~CloudDocs/fileName

cd ~/Library/Mobile\ Desktop/com~apple~CloudDocs/Desktop/fileName

cd ~/Desktop/fileName
```

but none seem to work.

It would be great if someone could help me figure out how to access this file via terminal as nothing seems to come up on the internet (only articles concerning iCloud Documents).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in OSX Mojave (I'm in 10.15 beta)the location is:

```
/Users/MyLoginID/Library/CloudStorage/iCloudDrive
```

where MyLoginID is your username.

Terminal is more secure in Mojave so you need to go to system preferences/security and privacy and the 'privacy' tab. in the box to the left, roll down to "full disk access" and check the box next to "terminal" otherwise it won't let you access the directory.

If you want to make a quick link in your home directory enter the command:

```
ln -s /Users/MyLoginID/Library/CloudStorage/iCloudDrive iCloud
```

Answer (score 1):

As of macOS Monterey (version 12) the path to the iCloud Documents folder is

```
cd ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com\~apple\~CloudDocs/
```

In case that ever changes, you can just drag any iCloud Drive file from Finder to the Terminal and the path will be pasted.